# Linux + wxPython = проблема при работе с wx.ScreenDC

Tags: python, linux, fedora, screenshots, wxpython

товарищи.

Возникли большие трудности при работе с `wxPython`, а именно контекстом `Display`, под `Linux Fedora 28`.

```
import wx
app = wx.App()
print(wx.GetDisplaySize())
s = wx.ScreenDC()
print(s.Size)
```

Вывод:

> ```
> (3286, 1080)
> (0, 0)
> ```

В чём может быть проблема и куда копать? Мне необходимо выполнять снятие снимка экрана. Но `ScreenDC` утверждает, что экран имеет нулевые размеры, в то время, как сами размеры дисплея методом `GetDisplaySize` определяются корректно (сейчас у меня 2 монитора, но даже при отключении второго монитора, ожидаемый результат не достигается)

Целевая функция выглядит так:

```
def take_screenshot():
    """
    Возвращает bitmap снимка экрана
    :return:
    """

    dc = wx.ScreenDC()
    print(dc.IsOk() or "False")
    size = wx.GetDisplaySize()

    w = size[0]
    h = size[1]
    bmp = wx.Bitmap(size)
    mem = wx.MemoryDC(bmp)
    mem.Blit(0, 0, w, h, dc, 0, 0)
    del mem  # Release bitmap
    return bmp
```

Тот же модуль `mss` возвращает вызывает ошибку в `X`

```
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  73 (X_GetImage)
  Serial number of failed request:  16
  Current serial number in output stream:  16
```

Пока тестировал под `Windows` не сталкивался с проблемами `wxPython`.

Опытным путём было выяснено, что подобные ошибки возникают только при использовании **интегрированного видео** (проверялось на ноутбуках с i5-8250U (gpu - UHD Graphics 620), AMD E1-601 (gpu - Radeon R2)). На ноутбуках с дискретным видео всё работает, как и ожидается.

Comment: Предлагаю попробовать `print(s.GetSize())`, хотя у меня на Xubuntu работают оба варианта (т.е. print(s.Size) тоже выводит правильный размер).

Comment: Основная проблема не в том, что нет возможности получить размеры, а в том, что нет возможности получить собственно содержимое окна. Добавил в вопрос текст целевого кода.